# Sinalizar o recebimento de mensagens

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

O cliente tem 7 lojas e uma matriz. Alguém na matriz com poder de decisão, vai ficar com seu mobile na mão com um aplicativo. Quando um funcionário de uma das lojas, precisar aprovar um desconto maior do que o que ela pode dar, ela então, através desse aplicativo envia uma solicitação, via `REST` e do outro lado o gerente recebe essa solicitação e baseado nas informações que o serviço levar para ele, irá aprovar ou não. Como eu faria essa mensagem chegar até a pessoa que tem o aplicativo? Em realidade, mensagem que eu digo é notificar o cliente que usa o App que tem negociação, ele então deverá abrir o App, e nesse momento consumir o REST e autorizar ou não. Não é um chat.

Comment: você pode utilizar o SignalR, desta forma a aplicação Web poderá enviar uma mensagem aos dispositivos moveis.

Comment: Eu faria com que o serviço enviasse um push para o aparelho, e nesse push você enviaria um payload com as informações para que, ao abrir uma activity pela PendingIntent da notificação, você consultasse no serviço o que precisasse e faria a autorização. Ao autorizar, enviaria outro push, mas para o sender original e ele liberaria a venda.

Comment: A dúvida é como o usuário do App vai saber se há ou não mensagem? No meu App do Linkedin ou do What's App, por exemplo, se eu tiver 3 notificações, fica em cima do ícone do App uma "bolinha" laranja ou verde ou qualquer outra cor, com a quantidade de mensagens indicada. O SignalR faz isso ou o que o CDS postou?

Comment: acho que eu fiz a pergunta de forma equivocada. Vou refazê-la

Comment: Não tem problema. Neste caso você teria que tratar internamente no app as liberações pendentes, armazenando uma lista de liberações pendentes. E no caso da push, você pode mostrar a notificação da forma que quiser no app. Isso da bolinha que aparece no app é nativo a plataforma ou launcher que usa. Ele somente conta as notificações pendentes do app, mas não funciona em todos os androids. Essa biblioteca aqui pode lhe auxiliar https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode utilizar [Azure Notification Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/notification-hubs/) para isso. Assim poderá gerar a notificação para qualquer plataforma.

No meu github vc pode ver um [exemplo de envio de notificações](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/AzureNotificationHub).

No seu aplicativo, vc assina o canal para receber as notificações:

```
var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

var hub = new NotificationHub("NOME_DO_SEU_APP", "Endpoint=sb://NOME_DO_SEU_APP.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=CHAVE_COMPARTILHADA_DO_SEU_APP");
        await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri);
```

E no seu serviço REST, vc dispara as notificações:

```
var hub = NotificationHubClient
            .CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://NOME_DO_SEU_APP.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=CHAVE_DO_SEU_APP",
            "NOME_DO_SEU_APP");

var toast = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01""><text id=""1"">Bem vindos ao VSSummit 2015</text></binding></visual></toast>";
var toastWithImage = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastImageAndText01""><image id=""1"" src=""https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-icon-set/512/Visual_Studio_2012.png"" /><text id=""1"">Bem vindos ao VSSummit15!</text></binding></visual></toast>";
hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(toast).Wait();
```

Comment: Thiago, vou fazer os testes e logo posto. Por isso não marquei ainda sua resposta. Precisa instalar via NuGet esses namespaces?

Comment: Sim, vc pode ver no repo do github que linquei. Lá tem os pkgs. :)

Comment: Thiago, uso vs2017 e está dando incompatível o App2. Como eu faço para abrir o seu projeto?